# How can I access C:\ProgramData in cmd

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, chocolatey

I installed Chocolatey using the NuGet Console in Visual Studio which reported it was successfully installed in C:\ProgramData and I could use it in cmd or Powershell.  I tried 'choco install git' which also completed successfully, it created a folder in C:\ProgramData but it has no binaries, just a config file. Also choco isn't included in the path and neither is git after installation.

Comment: chocolatey creates a shim in bin folder to enable that program to be in the path but in my case it is not doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there was an extra character(") in my Path because of which C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin was not included.